# tikzpicture will not display

Tags: tikz-pgf

I cannot get this code, which appears to be properly formatted, to display. It is a graph of two linear functions:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1]
\draw [help lines, <->] (-10, 0) grid (10,0);
\draw [help lines, <->] (0,-10) grid (0,10);
\draw [green,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3\x + 5});
\draw [blue,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3\x + 9});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am using Overleaf, if that helps. I'm using the tikz package, so I'm not sure what it will not display. Any advice? I'm really new to LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please be nice and replace the code snippet in your question by a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). This would help us to directly see your problem and test our suggestions. So it would help us to help you.

Comment: Note that multiplication is not implicit, you need to write `3*\x`. For plotting I would also recommend having a look at the `pgfplots` package.

Comment: And as the answer below says, your diagram, while it will show up, is far too big, at a width of 20cm (the default unit vector is 1cm), so you should scale it down as suggested there. Because of the size it's pushed to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale might be an issue. Try below to see if that is the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \draw [help lines, <->] (-10, 0) grid (10,0);
    \draw [help lines, <->] (0,-10) grid (0,10);
    % You can clip the x-axis and y-axis
    \clip (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
    \draw [green,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3*\x + 5});
    \draw [blue,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3*\x + 9});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If not then please provide a minimum working example to replicate the issue (with document class etc.).

**Edit 1:** Edited the code so that it compiles on copy-paste.

**Edit 2:** (i) Added an image as suggested by Zarko. (ii) Changed `3\x` to `3*\x` (iii)  Plotting the function based on range will require inverting the function which may not be possible for a general function. If you wanted to restrict the function to a fixed domain and range then that can be achieved by `clip` as shown in edited code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward changing my scale - that helped me get going. Is it possible to plot a function based on the range, not the domain, of a function?

Comment: @adarsh, please add to your answer image, which is drawn with your code (mwe).

Comment: @Zarko Edited. Thanks. raymiehumbert, I tried to answer the question in Edit 2.

Answer (score 3):

your code has more issues:

- image is to huge for one A4 page (it is 20 cm wide and 60 cm tall)
- used syntax for `\draw [green,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3\x + 5});` is wrong. correct is `\draw [green,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, {3*\x + 5});` (note * for multiplying)

see, if the following mwe gives what you like to obtain:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm] % scale your image to 1/10 in each direction
% grid
\draw[very thin, gray] (-10.1,-25.1) grid[step=5mm] (10,40);
% axses
\draw[->] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-25) -- (0,40) node[below left] {$y$};
% linear functions
\draw [green,domain=-10:10] plot (\x, 3*\x + 5);
\draw [blue, domain=-10:10] plot (\x, 3*\x + 9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up getting something I liked (though yours is prettier). Next time I have an issue I know to come in here with a minimal working example. Thanks so much!

Comment: @raymiehumbert, if any of the above answers solve your problem, please vote them (by clicking up-pen at top left side of answers) and accept  this one, which solve your problem on the best (correct) way. voting/accepting is the way how here say "thank you" :)